# Semantic-ui stackable doesn't work in Rails

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, grid, semantic-ui

I am using Semantic-UI for my Rails project, actually i'm using https://github.com/doabit/semantic-ui-sass , everything is fine except when i use "stackable" for a responsive grid.

I am using the next official example:

```
<h3 class="ui center aligned header">Stackable Grid</h3>
<div class="ui two column stackable grid">
    <div class="column">
        <div class="ui segment">Content</div>
    </div>
    <div class="column">
        <div class="ui segment">Content</div>
    </div>
    <div class="three column row">
        <div class="column">
        <div class="ui segment">Content</div>
        </div>
        <div class="column">
        <div class="ui segment">Content</div>
        </div>
        <div class="column">
        <div class="ui segment">Content</div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="ten wide column">
        <div class="ui segment">Content</div>
    </div>
    <div class="six wide column">
        <div class="ui segment">Content</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

It works perfectly in a HTML file alone, but in Rails it does not trigger the media queries. I also tested using the semantic.min.css and semantic.min.js in vendor files without any gem and i am getting the same result.

Besides i have tested it in either Rails 4.2.6 and 5.0.0.

Comment: tried it and it looks like its working fine for me

Comment: @mrvncaragay thank you for try to help, i forgot add the meta viewport.

Answer (score 0):

I should kill myself, it was enterily my bad. I forgot add:

```
<meta name=viewport content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

Thank you for everyone who read this.